# Deleting objects once inputted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a simple web app, in which - I am trying to implement a feature that -

If a `word` inputted by user in the `Another models's objects` then the word will be deleted, I mean, I have stored `few names` on a model like :- *car*, *bike*, *rain*, and *calendar*.
And I made another model named `BlogPost`, So when user submit form and if the mentioned name in the `another model's objects` then the name will be deleted. *but* the name is not deleting.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')

class All_Name(models.Model):
    names = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
```

views.py

```
def new_blog_post(request):
    allNames= All_Name.objects.all().values_list('names', flat=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            formName = form.cleaned_data['name']
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            if formName in allNames:
                new_post.save()
       # Deleting Here
                allNames = formName
                allNames.delete()
                
            else:
                return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = PostForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'new_blog_post.html', context)
```

**What have i tried ? :-**

- I have also tried :-

```
formName.delete()
```

But it is not saving anything and not deleting the Name.

- Then i tried

```
allNames.delete()
```

But it is showing

> Cannot call delete() after .values() or .values_list()

I have tried many times but nothing worked for me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete logic is wrong.
Here's what you should do.

```
allNames = All_Names.objects.get(names = formName) #Fetch the actual record from the ORM and then call delete
allNames.delete()
```

The reason it showed an error when you called `.delete()` is because `value_list()` collapses the ORM abilities of Django and gives returns you a native python list format. `.delete()` is a ORM feature of Django.

Comment: I am not talking about the `unique` values, I meant to say, I will manually store the `names` in `All_Names` model and I will ask user to type a name, and if they matched any particular name then that name will be deleted from the `All_Names` model

Comment: ok please mention this inside your question and proof read it one time, I think I can edit my answer and give you a solution :D

Comment: You mean, i should access `this query` globally (instead of `.all()`) ? OR You mean i should place it after `cleaned_data` ?

Comment: No, you need to do this inside your if statement under you #Delete Here, remove those 2 line of code `allNames = formName` `allNames.delete()` and add my suggested lines